# Why no bounty after grace period has ended?

Tags: support, status-norepro, bounty

[Point in Polygon algorithm giving wrong results for negative points](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61302366/timeline)

I've answered this question after a bounty was started with a score of 2. No bounty was manually awarded and the grace period has ended. It was my understanding that I should receive half the bounty amount. From the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), **the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount** (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted).

Why didn't I get half the bounty in this case?

Comment: No, both upvotes happened before the bounty ended. In fact, the bounty grace period *just* ended (according to the timeline, less than 1 minute ago at time of posting this comment), and your answer was awarded the bounty as expected. You just didn't wait quite long enough. Compare timestamps (which you can see as tooltips by hovering over the times) in the [answer history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61352215/timeline) and the [question history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61302366/timeline).

Comment: Ahh this is strange. On the actual question itself the bounty "alert box" that appears at the top said that the bounty AND the grace period had ended prior to this.

Comment: @compuphys Yes, I noticed that as well. That's confusing.

Comment: I wonder [if we should blame caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: I cleared my cache a couple of times but the message remained

Comment: Sorry to be unclear. I didn't mean caching on the client side, but rather on the server side.